# Java Powers display table

Tags: java

I need to display an output like this:

Enter an integer: 3

Number  Squared Cubed

======  ======= =====


1       1       1

2       4       8

3       9       27

But instead, when I run the code, I get this output:


Number  Squared Cubed

======  ======= =====

3       9       27

In other words, I need to display the powers of an integer,including the powers of the numbers less than or equal to the integer.  The numbers of the lesser integers need to be listed but are not displayed along with the integer being entered.  How do I fix the code to make sure it outputs all of the integers that are less than or equal to the integer being entered?  There are no errors (i.e. red exclamation mark circles) but I need to figure out the proper calculation.

Here is the code:

====================

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Powers 
{ 

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Squares and Cubes Table");
    System.out.println();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";

    while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
            // get the input from the user
            System.out.println("Enter an Integer: ");
            int integerNext = sc.nextInt();     

            System.out.println("Number" + "  " + "Squared" + "  " + "Cubed");       
            System.out.println("======" + "  " + "======" + "  " + "======");

            for(int i = 1; i <= integerNext; i++) 
                  {      
                  i = integerNext;
                  int numberSquared = (int) Math.pow(i, 2);
                  int numberCubed = (int) Math.pow (i, 3);

             String message = "\n" + i + "       " + numberSquared + "       " + numberCubed;

             System.out.println(message);
             System.out.println();

             // see if the user wants to continue
              System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
              choice = sc.next();
              System.out.println(); 
                  }
             }
        }
   }
```

Help is always appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as Nikhil said: "Remove the line i = integerNext; It is resetting the value of I and therefore only last row is printed".

Secondly, move the first closing curly brace to before getting user input - you want to run the loop, and only ask about continuing when that's finished, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line  i = integerNext; It is resetting the value of I and therefore only last row is printed

Comment: Didn't work.  When I enter any integer, each table now lists "1".

Comment: As MPeti said Move closing bracket after the line System.out.println();  to before the line  
// see if the user wants to continue
System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");

Answer (score 0):

Your are almost there. Since you are looping from `1` to `integerNext` (which is 3 in your text), the looping variable `i` will get the values `[1,2,3]` each iteration, so you don't have to set `i` manually. When you do:

```
i = integerNext;
```

you are setting `i` to 3, so the loop will finish when it reaches the loop condition.

You may also want to put the `"Continue?"` check *outside* the loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= integerNext; i++) {
    int numberSquared = (int) Math.pow(i, 2);
    int numberCubed = (int) Math.pow(i, 3);

    String message = "\n" + i + "       " + numberSquared + "       " + numberCubed;

    System.out.print(message);
}

// see if the user wants to continue
System.out.print("\nContinue? (y/n): ");
choice = sc.next();
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquaresAndCubes {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Welcome the user
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Squares and Cubes table");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "y";

        do
        {
            // Get input from the user
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            int integer = sc.nextInt();

            // Create a header
            String header = "Number  " + "Squared " + "Cubed   " + "\n"
                        +   "======  " + "======= " + "=====   ";
            System.out.println(header);

            int square = 0;
            int cube = 0;

            String row = "";
            for (int i = 1; i <= integer; i++)
            {

                square = i * i;
                cube = i * i * i;

                row = i + "       " + square + "       " + cube;
                System.out.println(row);
            }

            // See if the user wants to continue
            System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            System.out.println();

        }
        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Basic way to do it with foor loop and some printlines**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What number would you like to go up to? ");
    int userInt = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Here is your table!");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("number | squared | cubed");
    System.out.println("------ | ------- | -----");

    for (int i = 1; i <= userInt; i++){
        System.out.println(i + "      | " + (i * i) + "       |" + "  " +(i * i * i));
    }
```